# Convert png file to ico with PHP

Tags: php, png, gd, icons

I would like to create a PHP script that convert a png file to an ico file. Is it possible to do it just with PHP ? How ?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 14):

The recently uploaded https://github.com/chrisbliss18/php-ico creates valid ICO files including multiple embedded resolutions from PNG files and other file formats using only PHP and the GD library.

Answer (score 4):

After some googling and light experimentation, it appears that an .ico file is basically a BMP with another file extension. I believe the ICO format supports more resolutions in one file, but a BMP seems to constitute a minimal ICO file. You should be able to generate BMP files easily with gd or ImageMagick.

Comment: gd does not save .ico files as I know

Comment: @php Sorry, you missed the point. If my speculation about ICO files being extended BMP files is correct, it should work.

Comment: Simply cross-saving a GD-created BMP format file as a .ico does not do the trick. There seems to be more to it than that.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.phpro.org/examples/Create-Favicon-With-Imagick.html) seems to suggest [Imagick](http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick) can do this.

Otherwise, you could do the conversion on the server using an external tool and server the .ico file. Tools to achieve this have been analyzed in Stack Overflow [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37590/how-to-convert-ico-to-png) (well, doing the opposite transformation, but I bet most of that software can do what you need).

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this directly though php built in libraries. To write an ico file, you will need to write individual bits and bytes by hand to suit the file format. The easiest way would be to use a third party library.

phpthumb is a good tool for this.

http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I would give floIcon a try: http://tech.flobi.com/test/floIcon/

Answer (score 0):

For my WP plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-favicons/ I am using this ico lib: http://www.tom-reitz.com/2009/02/17/php-ico-to-png-conversion/comment-page-1/#comment-14883 here is the code : http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-favicons/trunk/plugins/filters/convert_to_png.php

It works with almost all icons but some like an icon found here: http://www.slatch.com/ give me : Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 64 etc... on line 296.

So... if you have found a better .ico php lib than I can replace that one with another one :)

Comment: The code seems to be at https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-favicons/trunk/includes/server/plugins/filters now