# PHP GD icon output

Tags: php, image-processing, icons, gd, favicon

Is it possible to have the [`PHP GD`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) library output a [`.ico`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28file_format%29) file?

Is there a function similar to [`imagepng`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php)?

Comment: If you're doing this for a favicon, outputting as a PNG will probably work fine =)

Comment: SO has already covered this, looks like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628114/convert-png-file-to-ico-with-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be able to do it simply by setting the content type to 'image/png' and setting the the icon link ref to the php script that generates the icon

```
    $img = imagecreatetruecolor(16, 16);
    $blue = imagecolorallocate($im, 100, 100, 255);
    imagefill($im, 0, 0, $blue);

    header('Content-type: image/png');
/*
or if it needs to be the icon content type
    header('Content-type: image/ico');
*/
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use netpbm's ppmtowinicon program? GD -> file(xbm) -> file(ppm) -> file(ico) -> php stream, content-type = image/ico.