# PHP GD .ico handling

Tags: php, file-upload, gd

Users of my PHP webapp are permitted to upload PNG and JPEG images. Upload algorithm is following:

1. check extension by file name parsing
2. check extension by getimagesize()
3. recreate image by imagecreatefrompng()/imagepng() (imagecreatefromjpeg()/imagejpeg())
4. rename image
5. save to filesystem

Image recreation is used for security. Everything works fine. But now i need this algorithm to handle .ico files. It seems like GD doesn't work with .ico (there is no function like imagecreatefromico()), so i don`t know how to implement step 3 of my algorithm.

Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628114/convert-png-file-to-ico-with-php)?

Comment: @JulienLopez Not sure it's my case. I don't change type. I just need to recreate file so be sure there is no malicious code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/lordelph/icofileloader for a composer-installable class which can load .ico files into a GD image.

For example:

```
$loader = new Elphin\IcoFileLoader\IcoFileService;
$im = $loader->extractIcon('/path/to/icon.ico', 32, 32);
```

See documentation for other methods of analysing and extracting images from the icon file.

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me, if it is possible to save $im as .ico file, since GD has no imageico() or imagecreatefromico() functions?

Comment: You should be able to find several on packagist, e.g. https://packagist.org/packages/chrisjean/php-ico

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try it later!